# No module named joblib Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, joblib

I'm trying to run this : https://github.com/HansiMcKlaus/AudioSpectrumVisualizer

And so I followed needed to be done to run it.

I pip install all the requirements, ffmpeg and try to run with the default example.

```
% python AudioSpectrumVisualizer.py 'sample.mp3'
```

And I have the error message :

```
ImportError: No module named joblib
```

Which is weird, because I already installed joblib.
So I tried some stuff,

tried to install it again :

```
% pip3 install joblib                           
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.0.0)
```

tried to export the PythonPath in the bash and zsh profile files.

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages"
```

Nothing works.

I'm on Mac M1 and I never had any issue installing modules with python before.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have multiple installations of python itself, causing your program and command line to refer to the different versions.
An example to fix this would be to uninstall the old versions of python

Comment: What a beginner mistake I made.. 
I just had to precise the name of the python version I used. 
In my case, python3.9 script...

Answer (score 0):

run it with the sudo code, this might help!

Comment: Already tried, unfortunately it does not change anything.